# Ubuntu 17.04 won't start after login and password immission

Tags: boot, login, shutdown, windows-10, 17.04

I recently restored my laptop (Dell Inspiron 7559) to factory condition and I had to reinstall Windows and Ubuntu. Since I didn't want to pass through all the partitioning and dual boot pain again, I decided to install Windows 10 in the hard drive and Ubuntu 17.04 onto an SSD, pressing F12 at the BIOS loading screen to boot either Windows or Ubuntu.

I took out the hard drive where Windows was already installed, I mounted the SSD and I installed Ubuntu on it via USB created with Rufus. The installation process went fine, I booted Ubuntu and then proceeded to install some programs (a few compilers and a few IDEs). I even tried to restart to see if everything was fine and it did work fine.

The problems begun after I put the Windows 10 hard drive back on. Windows works fine, the problem is Ubuntu: it won't enter the desktop (it gets stuck on log in screen) and won't shut down completely, I have turn off the machine with the physical button.

What's the problem and how can I solve it? I really don't know what the problem might be, and I can't even run little tests since Ubuntu starts but loops in the first menu.

Hoping this helps to the troubleshooting, I remember I didn't understand something during the OS installation: the installation program told me to format the SSD because a Windows booting procedure was installed in there, I said to format the drive and then the program asked me to change something: I didn't remember the exact words, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with sda1 and things like that (if it wasn't clear from the beginning, I'm a noob).

Also, to be clear, I boot both Windows and Ubuntu in UEFI mode (again, not sure if this info helps, just trying to say everything I changed to install). Could these things I did be related to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install both of the operative systems. That's what I did:

- restored the laptop I'm on (Inspiron 7559) to factory conditions;
- installed Windows on HDD;
- cleaned the SSD on Windows with diskpart (from command prompt: diskpart/list disk/select disk/clean) without initializing it;
- disconnected the Windows HDD and plugged in the SSD;
- installed Ubuntu on SSD;
- plugged in Windows HDD;
- booted from BIOS the SSD with grub;
- updated grub (from bash: sudo update-grub);

Now the system boots into grub and it lets me choose what operative system to boot: I tested it yesterday (booting and rebooting with both operative systems) and it worked.

**ATTENTION**

Even thought yesterday it worked, now I have another problem. When I tried this morning to boot Ubuntu grub didn't work anymore: the system boots directly into the Windows boot loader and, when I try to boot into grub selecting a UEFI booting method from BIOS, I have the "secure boot violation" problem.